# is('checked') filtering method not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to see if a checkbox got checked with `is()` method, but it is giving an unexpected result. Either way if I check the checkbox or not, the method is returning false.

HTML

```
<form action="" method="post" id="place_order"> 
<input type="checkbox" name="tos" class="required check-condition" />
<span class="error error-tos" style="display:none">* This field is required</span><br>
<input type="submit" name="place_order" value="Submit Order" class="order-sb-btn" />
</form>
```

Jquery

```
$("#place_order").submit(function () {
    var is_tos_checked = $(".check-condition").is('checked');
    console.log(is_tos_checked);
    if (is_tos_checked) {
        $(".error-tos").hide();
        return true;
    } else {
        $(".error-tos").show();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/yogc5ypb/1/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to express checked as a pseudo-selector, i.e. prefixed with `:`

```
.is(':checked');
```

Comment: You can also use `var is_tos_checked = $(".check-condition").prop('checked');`

Comment: Well, one returns a boolean while the other returns the property value. The property value, in this case, would be coerced into its boolean form when tested in a condition, but still, if you want a boolean (as the OP does), best to use the method that returns one.

Answer (score 1):

I usually use `.prop('checked')`
So in your code you would change your line to:

```
var is_tos_checked = $(".check-condition").prop('checked');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to submit form if user checked check box then you can use following method also-

1.write following statement in html file

```
<form action="" method="post" id="place_order"> 
<input type="checkbox" name="tos" class="required check-condition" />
<span class="error error-tos" style="display:none">* This field is required</span><br>
<input type="submit" name="place_order" value="Submit Order" class="order-sb-btn" />
</form>
```

2.Write following statement in js file.

```
jQuery('.order-sb-btn').click(function(){
    var checkedValue = $('.required:checked').val();
    if(checkedValue == undefined)
    {
        alert('not checked');
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
            alert('checked');
    }


})
```

By using above code form will be submit if user check the checkbox.
To check example please refer following link-

http://jsfiddle.net/1eygh774/1/